# 2 hundred sixty thousand VS 2 hundred sixty thousands

Tags: singular-vs-plural, numbers, reading-aloud

> In the past three weeks alone, the number of people displaced inside Ukraine itself has doubled to **at least 260,000**, according to the UN's Vincent Cochetel in Geneva.

Is this "two hundred sixty thousand" or "two hundred sixty thousands"?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the correct form is "two hundred *and* sixty thousand".

The singular "thousand" is used when following a number, whereas the plural "thousands" is used in expressions such as "thousands of people".

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S., we say "two hundred sixty thousand" or "two hundred and sixty thousand".

I understand that in the U.K. they say "two hundred sixty thousands". Someone from the UK care to confirm or deny?